# Deflection coil/yoke needed - any ideas on where can I get it?

Tags: coil, monitor

One of our molding machines screens has stopped working well. We've found out that the deflection coil has been burnt at glueing area and few wires have disconnected.

Maybe somebody here knows if there's any way to regenerate this fairly easily without specialist tools?

Symbols on coil are: vs-58485 and A94Z8ct

The screen is Microvitecs 13L4S4033ASX

[image]
[image]

Comment: 1) shopping or buying recommendations are off topic 2) these are often custom made, I doubt this is a standard part which you can just buy somewhere. You might be better off replacing the whole monitor. It is 23 years old, time to move on.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie oh, I'm sorry then. You might be right, new monitor is like 1700€ as I have already found out so it's alot for 23yo part. Still, probably I'd have to buy one anyways. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried contacting [Microvitec](http://www.microvitec.co.uk/)?

Comment: @SteveG yeah I did, still no answer tho, hopefully they'll respond one day

Comment: Throw it away and replace it with a LCD monitor. That's the way the old machines got repaired, don't waste the time with repairing old CRT.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič have you ever done this kind of swap? I'm just wondering how much work would it take to change crt to lcd, if this would be only matter of soldering few elements I can definitely do that, but I miss some display-wise knowledge unfortunately

Comment: Microvitec ... wow memories ... what drives it? a BBC Model B??? Forget repair, move on to replace. It's likely there's an easy-ish way to hook it up to a - not VGA - but probably composite video on BNC - monitor. Was it colour or monochrome? Add pictures of the video input socket area, and  output of whatever drives it. Update the question with this info. Or phone Microvitec at the no. listed on their website.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to know what kind of standard is the graphics card: MDA, CGA, EGA, RGB, RGB Sog, RGBS, RGBHV, YPbP, YUV ....then you buy a converter to DVI or VGA and buy a new LCD monitor.

You can make a spacer or weld a nem holder for the LCD that can go into the existing case.